# Java =<<< operator

Tags: java, integer, int, operators, java-opts

In Java, if I do `x = x <<< 2`, everything works fine, but if I do `x =<<< 2`, it does not.

Is there just no `=<<<` operator in Java?

If so, then why is there an `=<<` operator?

Thank you.

Comment: There isn’t an `=<<` operator; it’s `<<=`.

Comment: Also, there is no `<<<` operator.

Comment: Are you thinking of `>>>`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You said that

> if I do x = x <<< 2, everything works fine

Are you sure? `<<<` is [not an operator in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html).

There is `>>`, `<<`, and `>>>`. There are also the corresponding `>>=`, `<<=`, and `>>>=` operators.

Comment: Oops, what have I asked. Sorry. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

```
`b >>>= 4` works fine.
```

<<< is not valid operator, you can shift only to the right without sign.